# Invalid month-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i

```
     for rate in ( select tgt.carrier_code, tgt.tc_code, tgt.exp_date, (TO_date(src.eff_date,'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') - 1/(24*60*60)) eff_date from mira_rate
    tgt, mira_rate_dummy src
    where src.carrier_code=tgt.carrier_code and src.tc_code=tgt.tc_code)
    loop
    update mira_rate
    set exp_date=to_date(rate.eff_date,'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
end loop;
```

When i run this query I am getting Format error.

How to correct this? I treid giving diff to_date options it says some .
Pls suggest

Comment: What datatype is `rate.eff_date`? If it's already a `DATE` there is absolutely not reason to apply `to_date()` on it.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name:Its a date only evn if i remove it says format errror. can you edit the query .i tried it says error

Comment: *it says error* is not a valid Oracle error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the question title means you got `ORA-01843: not a valid month`, this is probably down to your unnecessary `to_date()` calls as a_horse_with_no_name suggested, but it depends on your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting. It's easy enough to reproduce, but only by making an assumption about your environment:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'MM/DD/RRRR';

select to_date(eff_date, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') from (
    select (to_date(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') - 1/(24*60*60)) eff_date
    from dual
);
```

which gives:

```
        select (to_date(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') - 1/(24*60*60)) eff_date
                        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

or since the error's pointing to the inner select, just:

```
SQL> select to_date(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
select to_date(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

The issue is that you're doing an implicit conversion of your date; effectively:

```
select to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/RRRR'), 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
```

The implicit conversion renders that as `01/28/2013` (or with the time as well, *if* that's in your NLS date mask), and when you then try to convert that back to a date with mask `DD/MM/RRRR ...` it's trying to use '28' as the month, which is clearly invalid.

If your fields are already dates then your `to_date()` calls are pointless, confusing and in this case causing an error. You should be able to do:

```
for rate in (select tgt.carrier_code, tgt.tc_code, tgt.exp_date,
    src.eff_date - interval '1' second as eff_date
    from mira_rate tgt, mira_rate_dummy src
    where src.carrier_code=tgt.carrier_code and src.tc_code=tgt.tc_code)
    loop
        update mira_rate
        set exp_date = rate.eff_date;
end loop;
```

I changed your `- 1/(24*60*60)` to `- interval '1' second` because I find that clearer, but it has the same effect.

Your update doesn't have a `where` clause though, but since it was missing a `;` that might have been lost in transcription.